# Compiling SASS file into CSS string in JavaScript with loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, loader

I have a situation where I need to get the CSS string generated from a SASS file which has been compiled in JavaScript.

I have got a solution working with just CSS, using raw-loader

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader

Using the following code...

```
import css from '!!raw-loader!../css/styles.css';
console.log(css);
```

However for this I need to compile the SCSS manually before I do this step which I don't really want to do.

I would prefer to do something like this... notice it is an SCSS rather than CSS file

```
import css from '!!raw-loader!../css/styles.scss';
console.log(css);
```

But this returns some JavaScript instead, I already have a SCSS loader in my webpack config which looks like this.

```
        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: {
                        insert: 'head', // insert style tag inside of <head>
                        injectType: 'singletonStyleTag' // this is for wrap all your style in just one style tag
                    }
                },
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Are you generating a CSS file from your SCSS?

Comment: no it's being compiled with webpack into js

Comment: Ok, so I don't think raw-loader would be suitable as that's for importing files (and you don't have actual files).  Do you have an example of the output JavaScript webpack is generating?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have figured out how to do this, I have posted my answer below

Comment: That's great, glad you were able to find a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this...

```
import css from '!!css-loader!sass-loader!../css/styles.scss';
```

This puts it into an object which has the CSS as a string inside

Comment: Shouldn't it been `import css from '!raw-loader!sass-loader!../css/styles.scss';`?

Comment: If anyone trying to use this and getting an error `this.getOptions is not a function`. Use `sass-loader@10.1.1`.